# Trouble when painting a Form's Panel using Parallel

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, graphics, parallel-processing

I have the following event handler:

```
private void drawingPanel_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Graphics graphics = e.Graphics;

    //gridSize = 8
    float cellWidth = (float)drawingPanel.Width / (float)gridSize;
    float cellHeight = (float)drawingPanel.Height / (float)gridSize;

    Parallel.For(0, gridSize, y =>
       Parallel.For(0, gridSize, x =>
           graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, (float)x * cellWidth, (float)y * cellHeight, cellWidth, cellHeight)));
}
```

This panel is correctly painted when the form first shows up:

[image: Panel showing fine]

But when I resize the form, this happens:

[image: Panel showing big red X]

I have the following line on my form's contructor:

```
ResizeRedraw = true;
```

What may be going on here?

Comment: @HighCore I'm not trying to hack anything, I just wanted to improve the performance of my paint handler using parallelism, since each "cell" can be drawn independently

Comment: Pretty odd that it doesn't bang sooner, which does show that you didn't actually get a benefit from using Parallel.  But no, this cannot work, the Graphics class is not thread-safe.  You get the Red Cross of Failure when it bombs because two threads try to use it at the same time.  Armed and ready to go off at any time.

Comment: @MatiCicero you're clearly trying to hack stuff together because winforms' performance is horrible, and hence you resort to try to use parallel stuff. Use WPF, which can actually draw graphics without constant flicker, and you'll have no need to parallelize the UI, which can't be done anyways.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The drawing should happen on the same thread as the UI thread. By using Parallel, you run each iteration in another thread. This is expected bahviour and you can solve it by using normal for.

Comment: Is there some workaround to use parallelism without using additional threads?

Comment: Why did the panel was drawn correctly when it was first shown? Shouldn't the same rule apply?

Comment: Parallelism is much more than just using Parallel for. What you do in parallel should be independent, so that they can be run concurrently. When you have shared state, things get complicated. You need to deeply understand the requirements of each problem before you use the shared state in parallel. By nature, a bitmap or any other graphics object is not thread safe and should be used in a single thread. Also parallelism requires multiple threads.

Comment: About the initial paint, I can't be sure, but Parallel.For does not guarantee to run things in parallel. Maybe for some reasons it runs the startup draw serially. I'll dive deeper as I get to my laptop.

Comment: I understand now, thank you for the explanation. Will be waiting for your response